# Why npm is throwing Event.js 187 Error in my react native project?

Tags: node.js, react-native, events, npm, expo

While Working on my React Native Project I got this error :

```
events.js:187
      throw
 er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

and then it stop working.
I am using Expo CLI and an android device.

Comment: I would explore the expo issues: might be that one, https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/519